# Generic panic recovering in go programs

Tags: go, crash-reports, sentry, panic, raygun

I’m trying to catch crashes/panics from go routines that are created in my program, in order to send them to my crash-error-reporting server (such as Sentry/Raygun)

For example,

```
func main() {

    go func() {
        // Get this panic
        panic("Go routine panic")
    }()
}
```

[The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47808431/11532710) states a goroutine cannot recover from a panic in another goroutine.

What would be the idiomatic way to go about it?

Answer (score 13):

You have to "inject" some code into the function that is launched as a new goroutine: you have to call a deferred function in which you call `recover()`. This is the only way to recover from a panicing state. See related: [Why does `defer recover()` not catch panics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29518109/why-does-defer-recover-not-catch-panics/29518404#29518404)

For example:

```
go func() {
    defer func() {
        if r := recover(); r != nil {
            fmt.Println("Caught:", r)
        }
    }()

    panic("catch me")
}()
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/zhu-GKUOdAh)):

```
Caught: catch me
```

It is unfeasible to do this in every goroutine you launch, but of course you can move the recovering-logging functionality to a named function, and just call that (but deferred of course):

```
func main() {
    go func() {
        defer logger()
        panic("catch me")
    }()

    time.Sleep(time.Second)
}

func logger() {
    if r := recover(); r != nil {
        fmt.Println("Caught:", r)
    }
}
```

This will output the same (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/abJa8k7cgP6)).

Yet another, more convenient and even more compact solution is to create a utility function, a "wrapper" which receives the function, and takes care of the recovering.

This is how it could look like:

```
func wrap(f func()) {
    defer func() {
        if r := recover(); r != nil {
            fmt.Println("Caught:", r)
        }
    }()

    f()
}
```

And now using it is even simpler:

```
go wrap(func() {
    panic("catch me")
})

go wrap(func() {
    panic("catch me too")
})
```

It will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/rpkq3edFFlv)):

```
Caught: catch me
Caught: catch me too
```

**Final note:**

Note that launching an actual goroutine happens outside of `wrap()`. This gives the caller the option to decide if a new goroutine is required just by prefixing the `wrap()` call with `go`. Usually this approach is preferred in Go. This allows you to execute arbitrary functions by passing them to `wrap()`, and it will "protect" its execution (by recovering from panics, properly logging / reporting it) even if you do not wish to run it concurrently in a new goroutine. On the other hand if you'd move `go` inside `wrap()` it wouldn't even work anymore as the `recover()` call would not happen on the panicking goroutine.