# Golang lint rule to require launching a goroutine with a recover

Tags: go, lint, goroutine, golangci-lint

I want to create a go lint rule that requires all goroutines to be launched with a wrapper function that can recover from a crash on the goroutine (this will also take an onRecover callback that will cancel context of request). The pain point I am trying to solve is that a crash on any goroutine will crash the entire server - I want to protect against this.

I currently use https://golangci-lint.run/usage/linters/ for most of my linters.

Two examples of Go routine wrappers that will protect against a crash in the goroutine:

- [Generic panic recovering in go programs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56234983/generic-panic-recovering-in-go-programs/56235139#56235139)
- [How do you keep goroutines running if another one crashes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66475482/how-do-you-keep-goroutines-running-if-another-one-crashes/66475743#66475743)

Also please feel free to call out why I should not do this. Seems like an obvious idea and given that this lint rule does not exist I wouldn't be surprised if I am missing something.

Comment: A panic usually denotes a bug so recovering blindly will cause wrong results.

Comment: The purpose of recovering blindly is to ensure uptime. I would like to come up with a convention where we always recover from goroutine crashes but report the crash as an error that we track over time.
In terms of program execution, I think we will need a convention that signals back to the other goroutine that the crashing goroutine failed due to an unexpected state.

Comment: You should do that where it makes sense, like in the middleware of an HTTP handler. Then you can automate log generation as well. You can implement non-blocking heartbeats to make sure goroutines are still alive, and check with an observer goroutine. In general, you don't need a separate goroutine to deal with a panic, simply generate logs/alerts in the recovery code.