# golang text/template renders panic into output text

Tags: go, templates, panic

I'm trying to render template, but it seems that there are some cases when error can be rendered directly into result text:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "text/template"
    "time"
)

type MyDate struct {
    Time *time.Time
}

func (d *MyDate) String() string {
    // here will be a panic
    return d.Time.Format("15:04 02.01.2006")
}

type templateDto struct {
    Date *MyDate
}

func main() {
    s := `start
auto {{ .Date }}
finish`

    t := template.Must(template.New("test").Parse(s))
    buf := bytes.NewBuffer([]byte{})

    err := t.Execute(buf, &templateDto{
        Date: &MyDate{},
    })
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%s\n", buf.String())
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/E0fP2b0rMHM

this code output is:

```
start
auto %!v(PANIC=String method: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference)
finish
```

the question is can i prevent rendering panics into the result, but get an error on execution instead?

Comment: The sarcastic answer would be write correct code. The panic doesn't happen in the template engine but in _your_ code: in `MyDate.String()`. If your code doesn't panic, the template execution will also not panic (but return an error if something's not right).

Comment: Please note that a panic in Go is not a simple error state, it's not comparable to Java's Exception for example. In Go you return errors, and don't panic (only on very exceptional cases). Note that if you call a function from the template which returns a non-`nil` error, that is properly handled by the template engine. Do not try to suppress the panic here, avoid the panic.

Comment: I just want to be aware of any unexpected errors/panic and handle them properly instead of hearing about them from customers who received a emails with PANIC inside :)

Comment: Again, the panic is in _your_ code. If you want to avoid that, you may use something like this: [How do you keep goroutines running if another one crashes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66475482/how-do-you-keep-goroutines-running-if-another-one-crashes/66475743#66475743)

Comment: I understand that there's panic in my code. And it might happen that I accidentally overlooked or undertested something and ended up with a panic at runtime. But I want to avoid the appearance of panic text inside a template that, having silently completed its work, would be sent out to clients in an email. It seems like a completely understandable desire. I don't know how else to explain it.
The only solution that I see for now is to search for the word PANIC in the result text. :)

Comment: I thought it was quite clear from my post that I intentionally did not perform the check in the String method, so that a panic would occur there. It was necessary to demonstrate the behavior of the rendering lib that catches this panic and simply prints it in the text, which seems slightly absurd and something I would like to avoid.